# SourceMap 404 Chrome, FireFox Vs Edge

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, bundling-and-minification, microsoft-edge, asp.net-bundling

I have a web app with angularjs and asp.net.
I have implemented StackTrace.js but I'm having issue with the source map.

My source mapping is made with the ASPNetBundling https://github.com/benmccallum/AspNetBundling

My bundling is made this way
- new Bundle (angular and other framework js)
- new ScriptWithSourceMapBundle(all the angular directive that need to be mapped)

Now the problem is if i put my StackTrace.js in a "ScriptWithSourceMapBundle" it works well on Chrome and Firefox. Edge generate a bunch of 404 sourceMappingURL not found.

If i put the StackTrace.js in the "Bundle" instead, Edge is fine but Chrome and Firefox generate the 404 sourceMappingURL not found error.

The StackTrace.js got the min.js and min.js.map included too in the project.

Comment: i actually resolved it by adding polyfills and splitting the stacktrace in its own scriptbundle